# Is there a way to disable all animations on ios?

Tags: ios, kif

Callbacks should still be called. I want to use it for KIF testing. The purpose is reducing the test time.

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for but the class method on UIView [setAnimationsEnabled:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/setAnimationsEnabled:) is a handy way of having all animations taking effect without them actually animating.

Comment: Have you tried swizzling `animateWithDuration:` ?

Comment: no haven't, can you explain how?

Comment: `setAnimationsEnabled:` only affects UIKit animations, not Core Animation.

Comment: What about swizzling *-[CALayer addAnimation:forKey:]* to do nothing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest way is to set the `speed` property of the window layer to a high number. What this does is control the speed of animation; a value of >1 increases speed. Set a value high enough, and animations will take shorter than frame length (1/60th of a second).

This is the best option because it affects both UIKit and Core Animation animations. Starting with iOS7, a lot of the system animations are actually performed with Core Animation directly.

Answer (score 8):

Embellishing @Leo's answer:

If you don't need fine-grain control, setting the speed property of the keyWindow of your application will speed up all your animations in most cases.  So you just need:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.layer.speed = 5.0;
```

This can be called anywhere you want.  We have it set up in in all of our tests so that animations are always fast. (Achieve by subclassing or using beforeAll if your'e going BDD or whatever structure you want.)

Also, in case you're interested, we've seen an approximate 10% speed increase, on average, when going from speed = 1.0 to speed = 5.0, where 5.0 is effectively fast enough to be almost instantaneous.  This obviously will vary depending on how many animations your app goes through but given how easy it is to enable, it's a no brainer for most tests.

Comment: Thanks, this works well in viewDidAppear or later. Any earlier and it seems to be ignored or reset.

Answer (score 0):

**update:**

I tried this and it seems to work. Animations will "run", they just take no time at all...

```
static void (*__original_CALayerAddAnimationForKey)( CALayer *, SEL, CAAnimation *, NSString * ) ;
static void CALayerAddAnimationForKey( CALayer * self, SEL _cmd, CAAnimation * anim, NSString * key )
{
    anim.duration = 0.0 ;
    (*__original_CALayerAddAnimationForKey)( self, _cmd, anim, key ) ;
}

static id<CAAction> CALayerActionForKey( CALayer * self, SEL _cmd, NSString * key )
{
    return nil ;
}


int main(...)
{
    // head patch -[CALayer addAnimation:forKey:] to set all animation durations to 0.0
    __original_CALayerAddAnimationForKey = (void(*)(CALayer *, SEL, CAAnimation *, NSString*))class_getMethodImplementation( [ CALayer class ], @selector( addAnimation:forKey: ) ) ;
    assert( __original_CALayerAddAnimationForKey ) ;

    class_replaceMethod( [ CALayer class ], @selector( addAnimation:forKey: ), (IMP)CALayerAddAnimationForKey, "v@:@@" ) ;

    // replace -[CALayer actionForKey:] with a function that always returns nil (no action)
    class_replaceMethod( [ CALayer class ], @selector( actionForKey: ), (IMP)CALayerActionForKey, "@@:@" ) ;

    ...

}
```

This changes the duration of every animation passed to *-addAnimation:forKey:* to *0.0*, and also returns nil for all calls to *-actionForKey:*

You can't actually just remove the animations--they may have side effects and actions tied to their completion.

---

Further to what @michaels suggested:

You could try swizzling *-CALayer addAnimation:forKey:* to do nothing. (Maybe also *-CALayer actionForKey:* to return *null*.)

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static void CALayerAddAnimationForKey( CALayer * self, SEL _cmd, NSString * key ) { }

...

class_replaceMethod( [ CALayer class ], 
    @selector( addAnimation:forKey: ), 
    (IMP)CALayerAddAnimationForKey, 
    "v@:@@" ) ;
```